# Simple Rebus Puzzle

Tags: rebus

Here is a simple rebus for you guys to solve.

[image]

Hint

> It's a famous quote.

*Source: Google Images*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe a bit too easy :P

> I came, I saw, I conquered

Explanation:

> Eye = I
>  Camera - RA = Came
>  Saw (self-explanatory)
>  Constitution - STITUTION = Con
>  Queen - EN = que
>  Red (self-explanatory)

Comment: Damn, I'm on mobile and couldn't post fast enough.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Same. People here are very, very fast.